# Count number of sentences using REGEX and ignoring acronyms

Tags: java, regex

I try to count the number of sentences in a text using a regex. I came up with a regex1 finding all points:

```
([^.!?\s][^.!?]*)
```

After that I tried to find most of the acronyms by the following regex2:

```
([A-Z]+[a-z]{0,3}\.).
```

However I have a few problems:

1. If the acronym is at the end of a sentence, it is found (e.g. Since 20,000 BC.) by the regex2 formula. This is not intended, I only want to find acronyms in a sentence.
2. If we assume, that problem1 is solved, I want to merge both regex formulas together so that the final formula only outputs the real number of sentences. As for example we can consider the following text from Wikipedia:

> The National Aeronautics and Space Administration (NASA) is the United
>   States government agency responsible for the civilian space program as
>   well as aeronautics and aerospace research.
>
> President Dwight D. Eisenhower established the National Aeronautics
>   and Space Administration (NASA) in 1958[5] with a distinctly civilian
>   (rather than military) orientation encouraging peaceful applications
>   in space science. The National Aeronautics and Space Act was passed on
>   July 29, 1958, disestablishing NASA's predecessor, the National
>   Advisory Committee for Aeronautics (NACA). The new agency became
>   operational on October 1, 1958.[6][7]
>
> Since that time, most U.S. space exploration efforts have been led by
>   NASA, including the Apollo moon-landing missions, the Skylab space
>   station, and later the Space Shuttle. Currently, NASA is supporting
>   the International Space Station and is overseeing the development of
>   the Orion Multi-Purpose Crew Vehicle, the Space Launch System and
>   Commercial Crew vehicles. The agency is also responsible for the
>   Launch Services Program (LSP) which provides oversight of launch
>   operations and countdown management for unmanned NASA launches.
>
> NASA science is focused on better understanding Earth through the
>   Earth Observing System,[8] advancing heliophysics through the efforts
>   of the Science Mission Directorate's Heliophysics Research Program,[9]
>   exploring bodies throughout the Solar System with advanced robotic
>   spacecraft missions such as New Horizons,[10] and researching
>   astrophysics topics, such as the Big Bang, through the Great
>   Observatories and associated programs.[11] NASA shares data with
>   various national and international organizations such as from the
>   Greenhouse Gases Observing Satellite.

The above text has 9 sentences.

Regex1: 12 matches (D., U., and S. are considered as "full stops")

Regex2: 3 matches (D., U., and S.)

What I need now is a better regex1 formula to only find acronyms in a sentence and then "merge" both regex formulas to receive all sentences.

If merging both formulas is not possible (for any plausible reason), then only consider problem 1 because at the moment my JAVA program use both formulas seperated:

```
public void breakIntoSentences()
{   
    //Find all points
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("([^.!?\\s][^.!?]*)");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(content);

    int allPoints = 0;
    while(m.find())
        allPoints++;

    //Find all acronyms with length 0-4
    p = Pattern.compile("([A-Z]+[a-z]{0,3}\\.)");
    m = p.matcher(content);

    int allAcronyms = 0;
    while(m.find())
        allAcronyms++;

    numberOfSentences = allPoints - allAcronyms;        
}
```

Thank you in advance for the help

Comment: You want only words, right? How about `\w+([^\W\d])` ? http://regexr.com/3ar0d Using PatternMatcher you can count how much you have them.

Comment: No, the goal is to extract sentences from what I read. To count sentences he wants to extract them into groups and then count them.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a pattern:

```
.+?(?:(?<![\s.]\p{Lu})[.!?]|$)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/mF1zJ1/2)

- `.+?` is here just to match a full sentence. If you simply want a count, you can replace it with `.`
- `(?<![\s.]\p{Lu})` means *not preceded by an uppercase letter itself preceded with a space or period*. This is used just before `[.!?]` which checks for an end of sentence. This seems to handle the acronyms right.
- `$` is there just to force the non-greedy `.+?` at the start to match until the end of the text *just in case* the text doesn't end with a period.

This regex handles `[6][7]` as part of the next sentence. If that's not acceptable, you could tweak the pattern a bit by adding `[\d\[\]]*` just after `[.!?]`.

Comment: Thank you very much! This really counts the number of sentences correctly in both examples :) However if 2 acronyms are one after each other (e.g. Dr. Prof. Someone has encountered a problem.) the formula counts incorectly (here 3)

Comment: @Flu well, the problem with this is that you can't detect acronyms reliably in the general case. You can tweak the pattern in different ways (for instance: `.+?(?:(?<![\s.]\p{L})(?<!Prof)[.!?]+(?!\s*\w+\.)|$)`) to add more and more special cases but ultimately I don't think you'll get a perfect result.

Comment: That's absolutely true Lucas! I don't expect to get a perfect one but if it is possible to exclude all acronyms (your previous formula) and all double acronyms you could be correct in more than 90% of all cases. Because your last solution works well with "Dr. Prof." but if you switch them "Prof. Dr." it fails logically. Hence, if it is possible and if you could provide my a formula ignoring all double acronyms, I would be satisfied :)

Comment: @Flu java regexes seem too weak for this task (no variable-length lookbehind or backtracking control verbs) but I may give it a shot later. For now if you only want the count you can count the number of matches of `(?<![\s.]\p{Lu})[.?!](?:\s*\w+\.)*` *minus* the number of matches of `(?<![\s.]\p{Lu})[.?!](?:\s*\w+\.)+`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like all you want is something that checks that there was no capital before the period. This is pretty easy to do:

```
((?:[A-Z]\.|[^\.!?])+)[\.!?]
```

This uses an option of any non-sentence ending symbol or a capital followed by a period.

The more than one character also allows you to avoid recording three sentences for:

> Something like this...

Comment: Your example has the same number of matches than my regex formula (15). So the acronyms are not excluded as intended.

Comment: @Flu You can see it working here: https://regex101.com/r/tO5bC6/1 It's definitely skipping over acronyms. And I'm getting a 9 sentence count?

Comment: @Flu I just tested the regex with your code here: http://ideone.com/8SqA5k definitely gives my 9 *not* 15.

Comment: You are write I tested with the wrong text... My mistake! It works but has the same problem than Luca's formula (https://regex101.com/r/tO5bC6/1).

Comment: @Flu Of course these do, they are both ignoring periods following a capital letter. You can add other things to ignore but you'll have to do that by hand, cause without it being a capital there's no way for a regex to tell the difference between "Jon." and "Mr." To add "Dr." and "Prof." to my regex you could just do: `((?:[A-Z]\.|Dr\.|Prof\.|[^\.!?])+)[\.!?]` But as you can see you'd have to start adding a lot of exceptions to find every acronym.